# function within function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, evaluation

```
delFunc[funcform_, lstofparams_,lstoferrs_] := √Total[Table[(D[funcform, lstofparams[[i]]]*lstoferrs[[i]])^2, {i,Length[lstofparams]}]]
```

```
funcanderr[funcform_, lstofparams_,lstofvals_] := {funcform,delFunc[funcform, lstofparams, #[[2]] & /@ lstofvals]} /.Table[lstofparams[[i]] -> lstofvals[[i, 1]],{i,Length[lstofparams]}]
```

I want to evaluate the numerical value of "funcanderr" with some region of variables.

Suppose
`funcform[x_,y_]:=(A*Sin[x y])+B`
`lst={{A,5,0.05},{B,8,0.08}`

`x = 45 Degree`
`y = 135 Degree`

`N[funcanderr[A*Sin[x y] + B, #[[1]] & /@ lst, #[[2 ;; 3]] & /@ lst]]`

Result is
`{12.8056, 0.0933241}`

Now, how to evaluate "funcanderr" with the exclusion limit `Pi/3<x<2Pi/3`; `Pi/3<y<2Pi/3` within the range `{{x,0,Pi},{y,0,Pi}}`

Comment: Presumably this code does not do what you want or you would not be asking the question. However, you have not told us what you want the code to do. We have to guess what you want using only code that does not do what you want. At a minimum, add an example of an explicit use of `funcanderr` and the expected output.

Comment: Please see the corrected version. I have got the result as a central value with error. Now I need to find out the same with a range of variables and a exclusion condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

delFunc[funcform_, lstofparams_, lstoferrs_] := √Total[
   Table[(D[funcform, lstofparams[[i]]]*lstoferrs[[i]])^2, {i, Length[lstofparams]}]]

funcanderr[funcform_, lstofparams_, lstofvals_] := {funcform, 
   delFunc[funcform, lstofparams, #[[2]] & /@ lstofvals]} /. 
  Table[lstofparams[[i]] -> lstofvals[[i, 1]], {i, Length[lstofparams]}]

cons = (0 <= x <= Pi/3 || 2 Pi/3 <= x <= Pi) && (0 <= y <= Pi/3 || 2 Pi/3 <= y <= Pi);

f[x_, y_] = ConditionalExpression[A*Sin[x y] + B, cons];

lst = {{A, 5, 0.05}, {B, 8, 0.08}};

g[x_, y_] = funcanderr[f[x, y], #[[1]] & /@ lst, #[[2 ;; 3]] & /@ lst]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate@g[x, y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Since the scales are significantly different, plotting the second function separately:

```
Plot3D[g[x, y][[2]], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]